# How to do a sum of a column if a particular cell of each row matches a particular value?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to make a budget sheet for a trip.

I have 2 sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. One contains the steps of the trip. The other contains a dashboard with the sum for each of these 5 groups of steps: "food", "activities", "shopping", "hotels" and "vehicle".

My first sheet is like that (with 4 columns - the 3rd is the price):

```
1. Go to museum               45    Activity
2. Playing cards               5    Activity
3. Sleeping at Bohaha Hotel  123    Hotel
4. Take breakfast             10    Food
```

In the other sheet, I want to make different sums conditioned by the value of the 4th column, and using the values of the 3rd column.

The result of the second sheet in this example would be:

```
Food          10
Activities    50
Shopping       0
Hotels       123
Vehicle        0
```

How can I do that?
I can use a function if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en):

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C1:C99, Sheet1!D1:D99, A1)
```

Assuming description in second sheet matches description in 4th column (the formula is not going to do the stemming for you to convert `Activity` to `Activities` - you can use 1 column for exact match string and 1 column as reporting label...)

Comment: Thank you Aprillion. I found the perfect formula just before to see your answer : =SUM(FILTER('Parcours précis V1'!H5:H; 'Parcours précis V1'!G5:G="Restauration")). But thanks again !

Comment: Uh. Just used and searched some details about your solution. And it seems it's better than what I found... So I switch my formula with yours :D Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect formula :)

```
=SUM(FILTER('Sheet 1'!H5:H; 'Sheet 1'!G5:G="Food"))
```